# Limitations to generalized additive model (GAM)

Tags: r, regression, nonparametric, nonlinear-regression, generalized-additive-model

I don't quite understand the generalized additive model behind the [GAM package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gam.html) in R. It seems quite powerful with the ability to easily find complex relationships and confidence intervals for these as seen in the [R Graphical Manual](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=mgcv/man/smooth.construct.Rd&d=R_CC). Are there any big limitations to these models and is this why I cannot find an implementation in sklearn for Python?

Comment: GAMs are GLMs with smooth functions of covariates rather than more restricted parametric functions (linear, polynomials, etc). The smooth functions allow for some very interesting models but you have to be careful not to overfit.

Comment: How would I check that I am not overfitting without using CV?

Comment: A number of ways have been proposed - Full blown cross validation, GCV (which approximates the full blown CV without actually having to do it), or smoothness selection via ML or REML where the smoothness parameters is optimised alongside the other model parameters by maximising the penalised likelihood. See some of the references in `?gam` and also read `?selection`. There is also the issue of shrinkage, whereby you can add extra penalties to entirely remove terms from models.

Comment: how about fitting unspecified interactions?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, a propensity to overfit is a limitation of GAMs.  Another limitation is that the model will lose predictability when the smoothed variables have values outside of the range of training dataset.  Essentially, you are sacrificing predictability outside of your data range for precision within your data range.

Comment: Isn't the problem of predictors going outside the range of the training data an issue with basically all models?  I'm not sure if this would be more problematic for generalized additive models.  I wouldn't expect for instance that imposing an artificial linearity constraint would somehow alleviate things.  Maybe it's a question of bias vs. variance in extrapolating outside the range of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the biggest limitations to GAMs is that they cannot model complex regression paths that involve multiple responses or things like mediation paths. [Structural equation modeling (SEM)](https://ecologicalprocesses.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13717-016-0063-3#:%7E:text=Structural%20equation%20modeling%20(SEM)%20is,on%20pre%2Dassumed%20causal%20relationships.) can achieve this, but generally the tools for nonlinear methods don't seem as developed like GAMs.

GAMs also don't allow you to directly model things like skew or kurtosis, which may make them more accurate. While this isn't always a huge concern for people using GAMs given how flexible they are, one alternative if one wants more specificity is [GAMLSS](https://www.gamlss.com/).

Comment: I don't think the first one is the limitation of GAM. Otherwise, I can say that the limitation of regressions is that they cannot model complex regression paths...

Comment: I don't see how that negates my statement. They are both realities of both GAMs and other forms of regression. That is not to say that GAMs are useless, only that they can only handle a single DV (which I would doubt anybody would argue).

Comment: In my opinion, it is impossible to have one tool to solve all the problems. So I don't think it is a limitation for GAM. As a statistics student, I would expect answers like computational difficulties, difficulty to interpret, difficulty to understand the theory behind (The properties of Spline functions are so hard to understand and I spent a lot of time to read the numerical analysis book >~< Also, as Eric mentioned, the predicted data may be out of range, for example, poisson regression including an offset. In addition, the residual plot of gam is difficult for the beginner to interpret.

Comment: (I know there is a package DHARMa). Sorry for my poor English and thank you for your answer ^^

Comment: *In my opinion, it is impossible to have one tool to solve all the problems.* - Nobody is saying that. All statistical techniques have limitations and GAM is not unique in that regard. If you can't fit a path analysis with a GAM, a GAM *by definition* is limited to single outcome models. I'm not sure what is controversial about that statement.

Comment: By the way, there is one workaround called piecewise SEM that can technically fit GAMs as part of the path model, but these models have limited functionality.